# Flex robotlegs module throws null pointer exception (Error #1009)

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, robotlegs

I have a problem with an application that uses RobotLegs in a Flex module. I finally managed to load my module successfully, but when I try to add this line of code in the module view's Mediator:

```
view.addElementAt(applicationContainer,0);
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
at mx.core::UIComponent/getStyle()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:11128]
at mx.core::UIComponent/getConstraintValue()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:9083]
at mx.core::UIComponent/get horizontalCenter()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:9252]
at spark.layouts::BasicLayout/measure()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\spark\src\spark\layouts\BasicLayout.as:253]
at spark.components.supportClasses::GroupBase/measure()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\spark\src\spark\components\supportClasses\GroupBase.as:1148]
at mx.core::UIComponent/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::measureSizes()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:8506]
at mx.core::UIComponent/validateSize()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:8430]
at spark.components::Group/validateSize()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\spark\src\spark\components\Group.as:1012]
at mx.managers::LayoutManager/validateSize()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\LayoutManager.as:665]
at mx.managers::LayoutManager/doPhasedInstantiation()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\LayoutManager.as:816]
at mx.managers::LayoutManager/doPhasedInstantiationCallback()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\LayoutManager.as:1180]
```

Why is this happening? The component that I am trying to add is a Group component, any ideas?

for more information i dont use modular robotlegs because the module is loadad in an application that already implements pure robotlegs, so i want to reduce efort to implements modular robotlegs, is a big project, my module loads successfuly but the problems happends when i fire a event that changes the state view of the module for show another component, i use ApplicationDomain.currentDomain in the ModuleLoader.

Answer (score 0):

I searched around a bit and came across [this post](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/619399?tstart=0) on Adobe Forums. Someone seems to have the same problem, and it doesn't look like it's related to RobotLegs at all.

Not knowing any of your actual application code, I can't be entirely sure about this, but I believe it's a good guess that your application simply does not pass initialization values to the module correctly.

Following the advice in the second to last reply of the above mentioned post:

> Instead of using the name of the module, [module name], in the main
>   application, use an interface that [the module] implements.

you should get to [this article](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf64277-7fea.html#WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7d1d) about implementing a common interface between module and application.  Try to adopt this to your particular module and see if your problem still exists.

Comment: i am already using a interface, like the tutorial of your link.

Comment: Perhaps you should share that with us. Along with the code that invokes it.

Comment: Did you happen to find a solution to this? I'm making a modular Flex application with Robotlegs and I'm getting the same error. My module does implement an interface through which my main application communicates with it.

Comment: weltraumpirat is right; this error has nothing to do with Robotlegs. This error occurs if you refer to your module class in your main application. In my case, the error occurred because I was mapping a module class to a mediator like this: `mediatorMap.mapView(MyModule, MyModuleMediator);`. I changed this to `mediatorMap.mapView(moduleLoader.child, MyModuleMediator); mediatorMap.createMediator(moduleLoader.child);` to solve the problem.